# Stop Android Studio from wrapping methods and constructors

Tags: android, formatting, android-studio

How can I stop Android Studio from wrapping method lines and constructors?

This is how Android Studio currently does it:

**A class**

```
public class Foo {

    public Foo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs); }
}
```

**A Method**

```
public static void doSomething(Foo foo) { foo.doWork(); }
```

This is how I would like it:

**A class**

```
public class Foo {

    public Foo(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
        super(context, attrs); 
    }
}
```

**A Method**

```
public static void doSomething(Foo foo) { 
    foo.doWork(); 
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. What do you actually want to see in the formatting? Edit your question to make it clear how Android Studio does it and how you want it.

Comment: Hmm, OK. Are you sure you haven't changed any editor settings? The way you want it is basically the convention used by most Java programmers - I'm surprised Android Studio would do that. What version of AS are you using?

Comment: Go to Configure -> Settings -> Code Style. Choose Java then look at the Wrapping & Braces tab.

Answer (score 22):

Navigate to

```
Settings >> Editor >> General >> Code Folding
```

You will find `One-line methods` checked there. Uncheck it. There are also other settings, you can change as you need. I attached the screenshot too.

[image]

Finally Restart your IDE. Done!

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 9):

Go to `File → Settings...` and move along.

[image]

Options you want there should be self-explanatory.

Comment: Those are unchecked by default in Android Studio, which is what the OP would want, except despite being unchecked, if you run the formatter in Android Studio, it puts the code on one line. It behaves as if those three are checked, even when they aren't.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it would seem like this is what I want, but mine are already unchecked and Android Studio (v2.2.3) is doing this to (what it thinks should be) one-line methods: `public boolean deleteGoal(long goalId) {
        return dbHelper.deleteGoal(goalId);
    }`

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE

According to stable android-studio version 3.0

Move to :

> Settings --> Editor --> General --> Code Folding

You will find **Method Bodies** to closes all method's body and **One-line methods** wrap it in oneline.

**UNCHECK both.**

Now Restart android-studio **OR** for class just close and reopen the same.

[image]